Trying to remove the background of color icon in ggplot legend
I'm trying to remove the gray box behind the color icon in the legend of this graph. Wondering if the issue is that I'm using geom_col() so the color aesthetic is just the outline of the column. Does anyone know if I can keep my use of geom_col() and just remove this background?
rain_flow_colors <- c("Precipitation" = "skyblue", 
                      "Inflow" = "black")

ggplot(rainfall_flow_mm)+
   geom_col(aes(x = Date, y = precip_mm, color = "Precipitation"))+
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = flow_depth, color = "Inflow"))+
  facet_wrap(~study_yr, scales = "free_x")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = rain_flow_colors)+
  scale_color_manual(values = rain_flow_colors)+
  labs(x = "Date",
       y = "Depth (mm)",
       color = NULL,
       fill = NULL)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") 


When I use the fill aesthetic instead, the legend looks better, with a blue skyblue box, instead of a line, but I want the line if possible. Maybe I'll just have to change my geom?[


scale_fill_manual(values = rain_flow_colors, guide = 'none')?

the key_glyph parameter of geom_col() takes a draw_key_* function, either will work. See ?draw_key for help
geom_col(aes(x = Date, y = precip_mm, color = "Precipitation"), key_glyph = draw_key_path) +

or the name of the funcion without the prefix "draw_key_"
geom_col(aes(x = Date, y = precip_mm, color = "Precipitation"), key_glyph = "path") +

